# Summation or Algebra?

Tags: summation

I am trying to visualize the concept that should be involved with this problem: What is $x$ in the equation 
$$(x-1)-2(x-2)+3(x-3)-4(x-4)+\dots-10(x-10)=0\quad ?$$

What should I do? Express in summation (which I find very hard) or just algebra?

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}i(x-i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}ix-i^2=x\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}i^2=\frac{x\cdot 10\cdot11}2-\frac{10\cdot11\cdot21}6=0\to55x=385$$

Comment: Your sum is $$\sum_{r=1}^{10}r(x-r)$$

Comment: the sign changes every term which would denote that (-1) is raised to the power of n (referring to the number of terms) then again multiplied to(-1). That would raise another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by using Gauss' trick
$$\begin{align}(x-1)-10(x-10)&=-9(x-11)\\
-2(x-2)+9(x-9)&=7(x-11)\\
3(x-3)-8(x-8)&=-5(x-11)\\
-4(x-4)+7(x-7)&=3(x-11)\\
5(x-5)-6(x-6)&=-(x-11)
\end{align}$$
and each term is zero for $x=11$.

Comment: I like this a lot. Also noting that adding the next term [which would be +11(x--11)] maintains the factor $x-11$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I love this too.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-1)-2(x-2)+3(x-3)-4(x-4)+\dots-10(x-10)=0$$
$$\implies x(1-2+3-4+\cdots-10)-(1-2^2+3^2-\cdots-10^2)=0$$
$$\implies x=\dfrac{1-2^2+3^2-\cdots-10^2}{1-2+3-4+\cdots-10}$$
$$\implies x=11$$

---

$$1-2^2+3^2-\cdots-10^2=\sum_{n=1}^{10}(-1)^{n-1}n^2=-55$$
and $$1-2+3-4+\cdots-10=\sum_{n=1}^{10}(-1)^{n-1}n=-5$$

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome @Patrick Cañete

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do with problems like this is look for helpful patterns. There is clearly a pattern involved, but does it simplify into something you can work with. The first few terms come out as

$$x-1=0$$$$-x+3=0$$$$2x-6=0$$$$-2x+10=0$$$$3x-15=0$$$$-3x+21=0$$Does that help you to see what is going on.